# How do i connect cpanel mysql database to prisma orm?

Tags: mysql, prisma, next.js13

I am currently developing a Next.js app for a client and have been tasked with collecting user information, which needs to be stored in their cPanel MySQL database. However, I'm facing challenges in establishing the connection between the database and Prisma. It's worth mentioning that I am relatively new to cPanel.

This is the url I'm using to establish the connection below

```js
DATABASE_URL=mysql://judor_jz:******@127.0.0.1:3306/judor_vc
```

The error I'm getting

```
Error: P1001: Can't reach database server at `127.0.0.1`:`3306`

Please make sure your database server is running at `127.0.0.1`:`3306`.
```

Comment: Ideally you have a REST function, so that a local Webserver that receives the data and stores it

Comment: Mysql is mysql, whether you manage it through cpanel or not, has no influence on how to connect to it. You wrote you were facing challenges with establishing the connection, however you forgot to mention what those challenges are, so we cannot help you.

Comment: `Can't reach database server at 127.0.0.1` - is the server really at your local machine? can you connect to it from localhost using `mysql` and verify that `mysqld` in list of processes?

Answer (score 0):

[You can use the "remote MySQL" service or feature provided by your chosen hosting service.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r38vV.jpg)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).